# MD5 hash different between sources - different hash for the same string

Tags: hash, md5

I've implemented the md5 source from a crypt lib from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcrypt/

The string I'm passing to md5 is `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890.`

From the md5 provided by my system I receive this hash `26756d7b34ff23859568262596dc159d` but from what I've implemented I'm getting, consistently, `11e16a7373051c77c51798c45611581c`.

I'm sure both follow the standards for md5 but just use a different "starting point" to calculate the hashes?  Should I continue using the methods I found over on sourceforge?

I'm very unfamiliar with terms in general; when I say "starting point" I'm imagining just this method in `md5.c` from libcrypt :

```
void md5_init(union hash_state * md)
{
 md->md5.state[0] = 0x67452301; // are these values standard to begin with?
 md->md5.state[1] = 0xefcdab89;
 md->md5.state[2] = 0x98badcfe;
 md->md5.state[3] = 0x10325476;
 md->md5.curlen = md->md5.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: I get your system hash `2675...` only when I include a line return, which you would get if you `echo ABCD... | md5sum`. Are you including that in your code? For simplicity you might check against the empty string, whose md5 hash is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`, reproduce with `echo -n | md5sum`.

Comment: @otus I added what I meant by "starting point";

Comment: @CaptainMurphy I tried `echo -ne ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890. | md5` and got `1926c36634965ee9d911cae458f6badb`; edit: I see now what you mean regarding testing just an empty string. I get this for empty string on my implementation: `85bd946a585af9fd3fb9eda68707c1d8`

Comment: Yes, that is the normal MD5 IV, described e.g. [here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt). You probably have some kind of bug elsewhere in your code, but debugging is off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about debugging code.

Comment: @otus: understood! I'll do some debugging then. Thanks all.

Comment: @otus: actually on second thought.... would it matter to mention my implementation is actually in javascript and not c?

Comment: @qumonio, in that case the first thing I would look at is string encoding. You could ask on Stack Overflow if you have a particular issue you are not sure you got right.